# $\arccos$ of an imaginary number

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

How can I solve a $\arccos$ of an imaginary number? like:

$$\cos x = 0.9i$$

Because I can't make the $\arccos$ of a imaginary number

Comment: You can use the identity $\cos^{-1}(x)=i\log\left(x-i\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$

Comment: The result must be a imaginary number? or it´s possible to get a real number?

Comment: @user1350772: All the results will be imaginary, since the cosine function is *real-valued* when restricted to the reals, and $0.9i$ is not real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can start by noting that $$\cos x=\frac12\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right).$$ Thus, multiplying by $2e^{ix}$ yields $$e^{2ix}+1=1.8ie^{ix},$$ and the substitution $u=e^{ix}$ yields $$u^2+1=1.8iu.$$ Solve this quadratic for $u,$ then go from there. Bear in mind that $e^{2\pi i}=1,$ so there will be not just two solutions, but infinitely many.

Comment: It is useful to mention OP that this is the way to derive the identity in the comments.