# How to calculate arccos of complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I want to know what can I do to calculate the **acos** of a complex number. I looked at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619692/arccos-of-an-imaginary-number) on this site but that only work for imaginary numbers.

Given the complex number:

$$ \arccos(2 + 3i) $$

How can I calculate it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One solves *equations* or *problems*,  not numbers. You want to *calculate* $\arccos(2+3 i)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=\arccos(2+3i)$
$2+3i=\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$; $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=4+6i$; $u^2-(4+6i)u+1=0$ where $u=e^{iz}$; $$u={4+6i\pm\sqrt{(4+6i)^2-4}\over2}={4+6i\pm\sqrt{-24+48i}\over2}=2+3i\pm\sqrt{-6+12i}$$ so we need to find $\sqrt{-6+12i}$.

Let $\sqrt{-6+12i}=r+si$. Then $-6+12i=r^2-s^2+2rsi$, so $$r^2-s^2=-6,\qquad 2rs=12$$ Then $$(r^2+s^2)^2=(r^2-s^2)^2+(2rs)^2=36+144=180$$ so $r^2+s^2=\sqrt{180}=6\sqrt5$. Then $2r^2=6\sqrt5-6$ and $2s^2=6\sqrt5+6$, so $$r=\sqrt{3\sqrt5-3},\qquad s=\sqrt{3\sqrt5+3}$$ So $e^{iz}=u=2+3i\pm(\sqrt{3\sqrt5-3}+\sqrt{3\sqrt5-3}i)$, and $z=-i\log u$.

But how do we find $\log u$, when $u$ is a complex number? Let's do it in general. Write $a+bi=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\arctan(b/a)}$. Then $\log(a+bi)=(1/2)\log(a^2+b^2)+i\arctan(b/a)$.

Comment: The last formula for the phase of $a+bi$ works only when $a>0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part

Comment: +1 I thought $\cos (x) \cosh(y) – i \sin(x)\sinh(y) = A + iB$ is the only lengthy option.
However, There is an easy way to find square root of complex numbers.

Comment: @Gary, I may have slipped a thing or two under the rug, but I trust that if OP goes over it carefully, maybe tries to work out an example, all oversights will be found and corrected.

Comment: Thanks Gerry for the full explanation, really appreciated. I´m writing a program to compute some operation with complex numbers, I have just tried this approach and it worked ok for all $a > 0$, but when $a < 0$ It only computes right the imaginary part, and for $a=0$ it returns both parts wrong as @Gary said. I supposed it has someting to do with the $arctan(b/a)$. Is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios Just look at the Wikipedia link gave. It gives you the correct formulae when $a \leq 0$.

Comment: Yes, now it's working, thanks!